# Integrate WooCommerce and Woocommerce Bookings on one page custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm currently developing a one page website using Wordpress and a custom theme and I'm struggling to understand how I can integrate WooCommerce checkout (and WooCommerce Booking plugin) on my index page, which contains everything rather than using /shop/ etc.

Is that even doable?

The website can be seen here: http://a-maze-in.com but the booking section is empty for now (it's live)

Any insight deeply appreciated.
Cheers.

[edit]
To be more specific, my question would be: How can I handle every step of the shop and checkout process on a single page? (that would be my index)
[/edit]

Comment: Given enough time/resources/money almost everything is possible. You'd need to ask a much more specific question. On another note, I love your site's design. Trop classe.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. :)I have now edited the question to try to be more specific.

Comment: Salut Antoine, what about [One Page Checkout](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/)?

Comment: Salut Helga. That looks interesting. Since I'm in a hurry I think I'll drop the one page aspect for now, setup the customise booking form (doing it right now) and use the regular checkout pages. Still a lot to learn and no time to do it properly. grr. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my main problem was wp_footer(); missing from the footer.php page on my Custom theme. That little thing wasn't trigging the WooCommerce functionalities (and more specifically the functionnalities linked to the Bookings Plugin)

I've amended that and now it's working on my page. I still have a lot to figure out (like how can I do the checkout on that same page) but now I can work with that.